# How to send Data through PJAX using minimal example for PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, pjax

I have been trying to send some data (which may be gathered using HTML FORM, or some arbitrary JS variable) to *slave.php* page called from *master.php* via PJAX. One way that i understand is to use jQuery to append data to the URL parameters and retrieve them in $_GET in *slave.php*. I instead want to use $_POST.

Here is my minimal working example of master.php and slave.php.

```
<!-- Master.php Start -->
<html><head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.pjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).pjax('a.sheetlinks', '#data')          
});
</script></head><body>
<h1>Master Page</h1>

<a href="master.php">Master Page</a><br />
<a href="slave.php">Slave Page</a><br />
<a class="sheetlinks" href='slave.php' data-pjax='main'>Load Data from Slave Page and Notice the URL</a><br /><br />

<div id="data">Master Data</div>
</body>
</html>
<!--Master.php End -->
<!--Slave.php Start -->

<?php if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_PJAX"])) :?>
Slave Data

    <?php else: ?>
    <html>
    <body>
    <h1>Slave Page</h1>

    <a href="master.php">Master Page</a><br />
    <a href="slave.php">Slave Page</a><br /><br />

    Slave Data<br />
    </body></html>

<?php endif; ?>
<!--Slave.php End -->
```